# Fetch last 3 month data as separate columns not rows for each user

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table "bf_monthly_bill" in which data against each users from another table "bf_users" is stored month wise.

Structure of my bf_users table is

```
id   | display_name
1    | ABC
2    | DEF
3    | GHI
4    | JKL
```

Structure of bf_monthly_bill is

```
company_id   | package_price  | bill_month
1            | 500            | Jan2k19
2            | 300            | Jan2k19
3            | 900            | Jan2k19
1            | 200            | Feb2k19
3            | 542            | Feb2k19
1            | 500            | Mar2k19
2            | 300            | Mar2k19
3            | 900            | Mar2k19
4            | 200            | Mar2k19
```

I want each company name with its package_price from each bill month e.g

```
company_name   | first_month_bill  | second_month_bill |third_month_bill 
ABC            | 500               | 200               |   500 
DEF            | 300               | 0 or Null         |   300
GHI            | 900               | 542               |   900
JKL            | 0 or NUll         | 0 or Null         |   200
```

What I have tried is

```
SELECT bf_users.display_name,first_month.package_price firstt_bill,second_month.package_price second_bill,third_month.package_price third_bill from bf_monthly_bill 
AS first_month 
JOIN bf_monthly_bill AS second_month ON first_month.company_id=second_month.company_id
JOIN bf_monthly_bill AS third_month ON first_month.company_id=third_month.company_id
JOIN bf_users ON bf_users.id=first_month.company_id
Where first_month.bill_month='Jan2k19' AND second_month.bill_month='Feb2k19' AND third_month.bill_month='Mar2k19'
```

The issue with this query is it gives me only those companies and their respective bills that are present against each month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `LEFT JOIN` to make sure, you get complete list of companies even though there is no bill for any month.
2. You have to create n columns manually or using a script.
3. You can just do simple join, no subquery is required.
4. Use `GROUP BY` to generate single record per company.
5. Use `CASE WHEN` or `IF ELSE` to create n columns and pick data from relevent row only. It can be first or any row, so use aggregate function to pick data even it is at any row for a group by making other row values as `NULL` as aggregate function exclude null values.

```
SELECT 
    u.display_name,
    SUM(IF( bill_month='Jan2k19', package_price, NULL)) as first_bill,
    SUM(IF( bill_month='Feb2k19', package_price, NULL)) as second_bill,
    SUM(IF( bill_month='Mar2k19', package_price, NULL)) as third_bill
FROM bf_users u 
LEFT JOIN bf_monthly_bill b on u.id=b.company_id
GROUP BY u.display_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select display_name,
       sum(case when bill_month='Jan2k19' then package_price end) as first_bill,
       sum(case when bill_month='Feb2k19' then package_price end) as second_bill,
       sum(case when bill_month='Mar2k19' then package_price end) as third_bill
from
(
   SELECT u.display_name,b.package_price,b.bill_month
   from bf_users u inner join bf_monthly_bill b on u.id=b.company_id
)A group by display_name
```

Comment: @BensonOO if you get performance issues with this query when data grows in the future ... Little hint factor out the subquery as MySQL under 5.7 tends to materialize queries used in the from clause... MySQL: 5.7+ tends to factor out the subquery on itself in the optimizer..

Comment: @BensonOO forgot to mention running `EXPLAIN <query>; SHOW WARNINGS;` on some MySQL versions can show optimizer internal SQL rewrites when rewrits happen offcource **Added:** but don't be surprised when JOINs are convered in the old comma joins internally

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
SELECT bu.name, 
    max(case when (bb.bill_month='Jan2k19') then bb.package_price else NULL end) as 'first_month_bill',
    max(case when (bb.bill_month='Feb2k19') then bb.package_price else NULL end) as 'second_month_bill',
    max(case when (bb.bill_month='Mar2k19') then bb.package_price else NULL end) as 'third_month_bill'
    FROM bf_users bu
    INNER JOIN bf_monthly_bill bb
    ON bu.id = bb.bf_users_id GROUP BY bu.name;
```

Output::

```
name    first_month_bill    second_month_bill   third_month_bill
ABC       500                   200                  500
DEF       300                  (null)                300
GHI       900                   542                  900
JKL      (null)                (null)                200
```

Here is  **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0927be/4/0)** demo